# Cannot validate data using complex check constraint case in mysql 7

Tags: validation, mariadb, constraints, case

```
ALTER TABLE
    src_branches ADD CONSTRAINT bmod_to_id_check(
        CASE WHEN bmod 7 THEN CASE WHEN id BETWEEN 0 AND 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0
        CASE WHEN bmod 6 THEN CASE WHEN id BETWEEN 600 AND 699 THEN 1 ELSE 0
        CASE WHEN bmod 5 THEN CASE WHEN id BETWEEN 500 AND 599 THEN 1 ELSE 0
        CASE WHEN bmod 4 THEN CASE WHEN id BETWEEN 400 AND 499 THEN 1 ELSE 0
        CASE WHEN bmod 3 THEN CASE WHEN id BETWEEN 300 AND 499 THEN 1 ELSE 0
        CASE WHEN bmod 2 THEN CASE WHEN id BETWEEN 2 AND 300 THEN 1 ELSE 0
        CASE WHEN bmod 1 THEN CASE WHEN id BETWEEN 2 AND 300 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END ELSE 1
END = 1
);
```

// my goal is keep my id in a set range when bmod = some integer
// i'm open to alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the syntax of the [`CASE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/case-operator/) operator:

```
ALTER TABLE
    src_branches ADD CONSTRAINT bmod_to_id check(
    case bmod when 7 then id BETWEEN 0 AND 2
    when 6 then id BETWEEN 600 AND 699
    when 5 then id BETWEEN 500 AND 599
    when 4 then id BETWEEN 400 AND 499
    when 3 then id BETWEEN 300 AND 499
    when 2 then id BETWEEN 2 AND 300
    when 1 then id BETWEEN 2 AND 300
    else 0
    end)
```

So `id BETWEEN x AND y` is an expression that is true (1) or false (0).

Note the [constraint syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/#add-constraint) too.

ref: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=8aa7061675e0a75ed1d5a40ef9d44a84)